# Populate and animate with json a view in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

In my AngularJS main view I have a list of links.

Clicking on each link should populate and slide in a set of JSON objects. Each one of these objects is connected to a link through a link_id field.

- How do I organize the routing so that, instead of reloading the entire view, clicking on a link will just slide in the content?

This is probably an easy question to answer for somebody with a little experience with AngularJS, but I couldn't find easy enough or clear enough examples.

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/zwLS7/

```
<!-- partial: categories-show.html (shoud include everything else, AJAX populated -->
These subcategories belong to category {{category_id}}
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="subcategory in subcategories | filter:by_category_id">

    <a href="#/subcategories/{{subcategory.id}}/topic-headings">    
        {{subcategory.name}}
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would not use routing in your case.

Comment: What would you use? I am just beginning to learn Angular JS and I am not aware of all the options yet.

Comment: Could you create a little fiddle?

Comment: I guess if even if you dont use separate partials but place all of their content in one page your views would still update. You might find `ngInclude` directive helpful.

Comment: Putting all content on the same view without finding a different way to pass arguments to the controller other than the routing will remove all the content of the view on click and make a new one: no animation is possible, and the rest of the content of the view is lost.